# How is this type of weather stripping replaced?

Tags: insulation, windows, weatherstripping

This weather stripping is about 20 years old, and obviously it's no longer doing anything. It seems like it's stuck between those pieces of wood, but I can't tell if it's glued in, or if there are nails holding it in, or if it's just a compression fit. Can anyone identify how it was installed? If it's really in there, I was thinking I'd just cut it off and grab some adhesive based stripping to replace it.

*Click any image for full size*

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen this type of weather stripping many times on sliding doors.  There is a flange on the weather stripping that fits into the mill work.  It is a bit difficult to remove, and even harder to replace.  They sell the replacements at most box stores.  It is important to remove the flange from a small dido (gap) in the frame. Putting the new one in is tedious and often frustrating, but can be done. It is truly a poor design.  Take your time, use a little wood glue as lube and a way to keep it in place, or use a surface mounted replacement. I have had some  success with self adhesive  pillow type weather stripping.  I feel your pain!  lol.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it is a compression fit with some kind of adhesive. It's not so common to find pre-manufactured windows with nailed strips, although you do get after-market ones. You can buy the weather strips in big packs and re-affix it yourself. I am not sure what type of adhesive is meant to be used but I would assume wood PVC glue would do it.